# which one is more suitable, "with" or "of"?

Tags: prepositions

I have the following sentence.

> The second metric is top-k accuracy,
>   which calculates the percentage of query images whose k nearest
>   neighbors contain at least one image of the same class.

In the above sentence, I use `of` in `one image of the same class`. But someone told me to use `with`. I can not decide which one is more suitable? Is it proper to use either of the two words?

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts are as follows:

"of" is used when talking about images in your case of the same type or class.

"with" would be used if "class" was an attribute of your image. For example "The image with the same colorscheme".

So in your case i'd say "of" is the correct word to use.

Comment: I also think `of` is more appropriate, but since I am not a native speaker, I am not 100% sure.